# how to select a field in mongo db corresponding to another field that requires a condition

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm query-ing a MongoDb but with this aproach i'm receiving just the field under the condition
SQL :Select collection_billDAte where collection_billDAtE="test";

That's what i got so far(MongoQuery with java):

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("Collection.collection_billDate").is("test"));
List<BAN> banList = mongoTemplate.find(query, BAN.class,
CollectionName);
```

That's what i want:

SQL: Select collection_billId where collection_billDate="test";

PS:The bill Id is an object of the same Collection
MongoQuery with java: ??

Comment: To select specific fields, you need to use _projection_. In Java, You can specify a POJO class with the fields you want, in the `find` method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.